# grep -c kills script when no match using set -e

Tags: bash, grep

Basic example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -x

NUM_LINES=$(printf "Hello\nHi" | grep -c "How$")
echo "Number of lines: ${NUM_LINES}" # never prints 0
```

Output:

```
++ grep -c 'How$'
++ printf 'Hello\nHi'
+ NUM_LINES=0
```

If there are matches, it prints the correct number of lines. Also `grep "How$" | wc -l` works instead of using `grep -c "How$"`.

Comment: You yourself wrote `set -e`, didn't you? That's what `set -e` does; it kills the script if a command returns a non-zero exit code in non-conditional context.

Comment: @AlexP I did. It shouldn't be returning a non-zero exit code though? I would expect grep -c "How$" and grep "How$" | wc -l to be equivalent. I tried the first at the suggestion of shellcheck: SC2126: Consider using grep -c instead of grep|wc -l.

Comment: `grep` manual page says: *"The exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred"*.

Comment: @AlexP I see, thank you.

Comment: `set -e` cannot distinguish between normal, "expected" failures and actual errors, which is one reason not to use it.

Comment: @chepner What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress grep's exit code by running `:` when it "fails". `:` always succeeds.

```
NUM_LINES=$(printf "Hello\nHi" | grep -c "How$" || :)
```